# Anyway to check whether jquery is called in view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am calling a `new.js` file from view in rails , But somehow its not working and i want to verify whether its the problem with `jquery code` or view itself is not calling `new.js` file at all.

Any method to debug this ?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your webpage, inspect element, click on the line where your new.js is meant to be called, and click on it to see if this file exists or not. Repeat the process to check for `Jquery.js`

If it doesn't exist, please add it on `/vendor/assets/javascripts`, and require it in your `Application.js`

If it is already called, it is probably an error in your code.

Comment: So to make sure of my understanding .. when i right click it ..i should see "new.js" in the html file mentioned ? am i right ? ..if its not mentioned then its not called ?

Comment: Yes indeed, you should see this. If it is not there, it is not called